# Finding the sum of products in a string

Tags: python

I need to make it so the numbers in a string multiply with the number next to it.This is what i have tried so far.
example: "1234" would be 20 because it would be ((1*2)+(2*3)+(3*4))

```
def sumofproducts(dig):
      for i in dig:
            a=dig[i]*dig[i+1]
      return a
```

Comment: You must convert the digit strings to numbers first. The "int" function is for that.

Comment: Hi, cast the string to Char Array and then do the math

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_of_product(dig):
  return sum(int(x)*int(y) for x, y in zip(dig, dig[1:]))

print(sum_of_product("1234")) # result 20
```